# Switching between high voltage power sources

Tags: relay, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

I need to get an LED to switch on once the voltage across a capacitor goes above 40V. It must then remain on from 40V to the maximum voltage reached by the capacitor which is currently 1200V. The circuit has to be independent from any other power source so the circuits must be powered off of the capacitor.

I thought about using a comparitor but that would require an outside power source to power the chip and create a reference voltage.

I am currently working with the idea of using two dc to dc converters as I can't find one that will cover the full range. The first converter has a range of 40 to 180V and the second one has a range of 200V onwards.

I need to build a circuit to switch from one dc to dc converter to the other when the first ones maximum voltage is exceeded. I also need to switch over to another power source when in between the two converters ranges so that the led is constantly lit.

I think this can be done using a relay but I have never worked with one before and I'm not sure how to power it when the max voltage is reached and where to power it from.

If someone could shed some light on a possible solution or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How much current can you afford to draw from the capacitor, and how concerned are you about efficiency? That would change the answer.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the current. I'd prefer to keep it relatively small so that the monitor doesn't interfere with the overall testing too much. Efficiency is not too important. The main goal is just to make sure the LED lights for safety purposes.